# maven to return the path of uploaded artifact

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have setup `maven clean deploy` to push the code to artifactory.
Once the code is pushed after/during the run of maven clean deploy I can find out the path where the artifact (`jar/tar/war`) was pushed?

Comment: You have the groupId/ArtifactId/version of it?

Comment: Yes. The only option is to form the url programmatically ?

Comment: use the url of Artifactory and add to it the GAVC from the pom file